# How to serialize a field of a non-primitive type (your own class) in a Storm topology?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-storm, kryo

The following exception is thrown while I run my *Storm* project:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.youtab.dataType.id.GUID
at backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultSerializationDelegate.serialize(DefaultSerializationDelegate.java:43)
at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.serialize(Utils.java:85)
at backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.createTopology(TopologyBuilder.java:111)
```

As part of my *Storm* project, I am trying to transmit an Object type *Event* from the first Spout to the first Bolt and then to use it.
Unfortunately, after implementing all needed changes and commits in my configuration variable - as described in the *Storm* documentations, it is still failing to deserialize one private field of type "GUID" which is one field from my own private class *Event*.

I have created the following serializing class:

```
public class GUIDSerializer extends Serializer<GUID> {
    @Override
    public void write(Kryo kryo, Output output, GUID guid) {
        output.write(guid.toString().getBytes());
    }

    @Override
    public GUID read(Kryo kryo, Input input, Class<GUID> aClass) {
        return GUID.of(input.readString());
    }
}
```

And I registered the serialize as needed:

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.registerSerialization(GUID.class, GUIDSerializer.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

All classes used as data type for attributes/fields must implement Java's `Serializable` interface. In your case, this applies to your `Event` class as well as all used members of `Event` like `GUID`. Of course, this applied recursively, ie, if `GUID` contains custom types, those must implement `Serializable`, too.

Providing a custom Kryo serializer is actually *not required*. Storm can use Java's default serializer. For performance reasons however, it is *highly recommended* to register custom types. In most case, it is sufficient to simple register the user type classes via

```
conf.registerSerialization(MyUserType.class);
```

In your case

```
conf.registerSerialization(Event.class);
conf.registerSerialization(GUID.class);
```

Registering a class allows Storm to use a more efficient (general) Kryo serializer instead of Java's default serializer.

If this general Kryo serializer is still not efficient enough, you can provide an own Kryo serializer (as you mentioned in your question). **However, the class must still implement Java's `Serializable` interface!**

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the `Serializer` class, but judging from the exception, you need to make your `GUID` class implement the [Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) `java.io.Serializable` like:

```
public class GUID implements Serializable {
//...
```

When in doubt, please post your current code for `GUID`.